# Facebook object returning unknown after login

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-login

Here is my code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>sometitle</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/dot-luv/jquery-ui.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_home.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <script>

window.onload=function(){ document.getElementById('start_button').style.visibility='hidden';}



  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    }

 else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'myappID',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.0' // use version 2.0
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '! You can now play the game! Click on Start Game to continue';
    document.getElementById("start_button").style.visibility='visible';

    });
  }







</script>


<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="true" data-auto-logout-link="false"></div>


<p>Some bla bla content here</p>

<!-- <form action="index2.html">
<input id="start_button" type="submit" value="Start Game">
</form> -->

<a id="start_button" href="index2.html">Start Game!</a>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="example.com" data-width="500" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>


<div id="status">
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

For some reasons, this code is not giving the expected results, although most of it is copied from the developers.facebook.com website. It should run the `testAPI()` method, but it doesn't. I checked in the console, it was showing the status of the response object as "unknown", after a successful login by the user. Any reasons where I am wrong?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you haven't set the `onlogin="checkLoginState();"` method in the fb login button. Hope adding this helps.